Python Error SSL как запустить игнорирование
Помогите разобраться. Нашёл пример по-моему вопросу: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67459911/qwebengineview-and-ignoring-cert-errors и оформил его в своём коде, однако программа всё равно выдаёт ошибки в консоль...
При загрузке веб-страницы через движок PyQt6 я получаю в консоль множество ошибок: [14196:5292:0605/144729.706:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
Код который якобы должен перехватывать ошибки:
class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def certificateError(self, error):
        error.ignoreCertificateError()
        return True

Код программы с блоком, где создаётся веб-страница:
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
  
        webview = QWebEngineView()
        page = WebEnginePage(parent=self.ui.TabWindow)
        webview.setPage(page)
        webview.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.google.ru/"))
        self.ui.TabWindow.addTab(webview, "Гугол")

Что я делаю не так?
